# Override Private function in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, bundle-product, magento2bundleproduct

**I want to override getSelectionItemData private function from Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php file.**

**Does anyone know how to override this function as I want to change the price from this function.**

Comment: You can not override private function.

Comment: So, do you know an alternate way to achieve this?